# Aptana type hinting for `$this` in template files

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

In PDT I can do

```
/* @var $this MyClass */
```

and eclipse will use that for autocompletition, suggestions and so forth... It's useful in template files which get included into a function of a class from a templating engine.

Is there an equivalent for Aptana Studio 3?

I've also tried

```
/** @var $this MyClass */
```

and

```
/** @var MyClass $this */
```

**EDIT**

I'm evaluating the use of Aptana, it has some advantages over Eclipse + PDT. So, "use another IDE" isn't really an answer.

`$this` **does not** get automatically resolved by the IDE to the correct class because it's used outside of the class definition.

Example usage:

- Template.class.php:

  ```
  class Template {
      public function render() {
          include 'template.inc.php';
      }
      private function foo() {
          echo 'bar!';
      }
  }
  ```
- template.inc.php

  ```
  <?php /*@var $this Template*/ ?>
  <html>
  <body>
    <?php 
    /* I want that when I type "$this->" the IDE suggests me "foo()" */
    $this->foo(); 
    ?>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Use a good IDE that supports them properly? EDIT: Although you shouldn't need to typehint `$this` at all, it's obviously the same type of the current class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to 3.0.7. It appears to be available in that version.

See http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1714

Answer (score -2):

The whole point in templates is to keep logic and views seperate, what you're doing there is adding logic with views so your not really doing anything that's needed.

You want to do something like:

```
<html>
<body>
{TPL.MY_TPL_VAR}
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your template class, you would have something like this:

```
$myTemplateVars = array('{TPL.MY_TPL_VAR}' => 'This is my content');

foreach($myTemplateVars as $key => $var){
    $output = str_replace($key, $val, $key);
}

return $output;
```

And the second thing would be that $this is a pre-defined "keyword" in PHP, which can only be used within a class, so you would want to initialize a new instance of the class by doing something like this:

```
$objTpl = new Template();
$objTpl->yourFunc();
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, IMO, using a templating "language" doesn't really help readability, but slows down code execution, since at that point we have an interpreted language (PHP) that interprets another language. If someone can write `{TPL.MY_TPL_VAR}` he can also write `$this->data('varname');`.

Comment: The idea of a templating language is to keep everything sepearate to stop the mixture of developers, designers and users not knowing what's going on. So If a designer who only knows HTML/CSS, they can go into the template files, update everything in one place and not mess around with any other code, and it will work fine. Where if someone goes into 3, 4, 5 classes to find one bit of HTML which should be seperated, that's when it starts getting less readable. It may not be directly more readable, but in general it will be.

Comment: the only difference between your and mine approach is that I use PHP itself as a templating language. 
The templates of course don't contain any controller logic. They do however contain minimal control of flow (ifelse, loops, etc). Most templating languages (smarty, etc) must therefore reconstruct these language structures and are therefore subject to an ["inner-platform effect"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I would disagree with using languages such as smarty, as you say they slow things down to an extent. That's why I wrote my own templating system. Anyways, I'll agree to disagree. I just thought I'd add my input incase you were not aware.